# Using PassportJS google authentication with the nodejs google api library

Tags: node.js, google-api, passport.js, google-api-client

I'm currently looking at implementing a google api, using the nodejs client:

https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/

I'm trying to use passport in order to authenticate, which seems to be working@

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback"
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function () {

      var user = {
        id: profile.id,
        email: profile.email,
        firstName: profile.given_name,
        lastName: profile.family_name,
        accessToken: accessToken
      };

      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
  ));
```

In my google auth callback:

```
app.get('/auth/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {

    //do something here with the google api

  });
```

I can get hold of `req.user`, and this has the `accessToken`

However, the docs for the Google api nodejs client aren't clear on how to use an accessToken.
The example included shows the OAauth2Client retrieving a token, but I guess that part has already been covered using Passport?

Comment: Yes, once Passport invokes the success callback, it's succeeded and has `profile`, so I assume that it has already done all the work of comparing tokens or whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `google-api-nodejs-client`, but this is in their documentation:

```
oauth2Client.credentials = {
  access_token: 'ACCESS TOKEN HERE',
  refresh_token: 'REFRESH TOKEN HERE'
};

client
  .plus.people.get({ userId: 'me' })
  .withAuthClient(oauth2Client)
  .execute(callback);
```

I assume you can just set the credentials to those provided by Passport, and things will work fine.

Honestly, though, I find these API wrappers really contrived, and recommend just using [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request).  That way you can access *any* API service from *any* provider using a familiar module.

Comment: I confirm, this works just do `import google from 'googleapis'; const plus = google.plus('v1'); const oauth2Client = new google.auth.oauth2Client;`